# O(1) in a Java algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have two endpoints, one responsible for receive transactions and other responsible for generate stats based on transactions from the last minute only.

To store them, I'm using a `ConcurrentNavigableMap`:

```
@Component
@Log
public class DatastoreComponent {

    private ConcurrentNavigableMap<Long, List<Transaction>> transactions;

    public DatastoreComponent() {
        this.transactions = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
    }

    public synchronized List<Transaction> addTransaction(Transaction t){
        log.info("Adding transaction: "+t);
        List<Transaction> transactionAtGivenTime = transactions.get(t.getTimestamp());
        if(transactionAtGivenTime == null) transactionAtGivenTime = new ArrayList<>();
        transactionAtGivenTime.add(t);
        return transactions.put(t.getTimestamp(), transactionAtGivenTime);
    }
```

I use the timestamp as key, so that I can get all transactions from last minute just tailing the map, as follow:

```
public StatisticsFacade aggregate(){
        List<Transaction> validTransactions = new ArrayList<>();
        dataStore.getTransactions().tailMap(sixtySecondsAgo())
                        .values()
                        .parallelStream()
                        .forEach(list -> validTransactions.addAll(list));
        statsAgg.aggreate(validTransactions);
        return this;
    }
```

so far, so good (I guess?). well anyway, the process happens in the `statsAgg.aggreate()` method, and this method should be O(1). My implementation is like that:

```
 public synchronized void aggreate(List<Transaction> validTransactions) {
        if(validTransactions == null || validTransactions.isEmpty())
            return;
        this.avg = validTransactions.parallelStream().mapToDouble(a -> a.getAmount()).average().getAsDouble();
        this.sum = validTransactions.parallelStream().mapToDouble(a -> a.getAmount()).sum();
        this.max = validTransactions.parallelStream().mapToDouble(a -> a.getAmount()).max().getAsDouble();
        this.min = validTransactions.parallelStream().mapToDouble(a -> a.getAmount()).min().getAsDouble();
        this.count = new Long(validTransactions.size());
    }
```

I'm not really sure that this is O(1) since I'm running through the list 4 times...I tried extract `validTransactions.parallelStream().mapToDouble(a -> a.getAmount())` to a variable and re-use it, but of course, once the stream is processed, it is closed and I can't do anything.
So the question is: is this O(1) and if not, is there a way to run through the stream and too all this calculations at once?

Comment: How could it be constant if you look at every element? Update the stats based on the single new transaction instead of recalculating them from scratch.

Comment: `.collect(summarizingDouble(Transaction::getAmount))` But how you figure this to have any chance of being O(1) as opposed to `O(validTransactions.size())`, eludes me.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I tried that, but if I update stats each time a transaction happen, if no transaction is added, there is no recalculation, and I get old stats (like, stats from more than 60 seconds ago)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't, actually.

Comment: What was your question, then? Performing an O(1) operation four times is still O(1).

Comment: I see, you want to get rid of old transactions. If your transactions are sorted by date, you know the next transactions that should be removed, so you can then update the average (see sliding average). Updating min and max is a bit trickier and you can get to at most O(n log n) in the worst case with a tree structure.

Comment: `.parallelStream().forEach(list -> validTransactions.addAll(list));`?? Clearly this is broken code. You wanted `flatMap(Function.identity())`.

Comment: Also, you can compute all these statistics in a single pass: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#summaryStatistics--. Given that you store everything in memory and don't seem to flush the old transactions, my guess is that your list is not very large, and that using a sequential stream would be faster that a parallel one.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oh, I understand your point now. sorry...yes, makes sense to me. so it is still O(1) because I'm calling O(1) operations. whats the diff between add to a list and `flatMap`

Comment: `ArrayList` is not thread-safe, but you update it from a parallel stream.

Comment: well, there is no need to -1 my post...sorry if someone here knows everything, i don't

Answer (score 2):

An algorithm that solves your problem has to be at least O(n) complexity, as you have to go through each element in `validTransactions` at least once.

And it wouldn't become O(1) even if you run 
`validTransactions.parallelStream().mapToDouble(a -> a.getAmount())` just once.

Comment: I think it's possible to create O(1*m) algorithm for this problem (where *m* is number of transactions leaving/entering the current 60s time block), but it would require completely different approach. Also when there's little number of transactions, the O(n) may be faster, as that O(1) in my mind is achieved in "O(60*m)" way (min/max for 60s block with 1s granularity). Sum and average can be done in O(1*m) easily.